# Where condition is not null

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using  a class named `Connection`.

Here is my class code:

```
public static string Username;
```

Then somewhere in my main windows form I'm searching in a datagridview and I use `Connection.Username`.

I want to set in my `SqlDataReader` do search

```
where Username = Connection.username
```

but only in case that this is not null.

Here is my main code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select UserName from CustomerTrans  where UserName='"+Connection.Username+"'" , con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
}
```

I want to avoid the case when `Connection.Username` is null to return all results.

Comment: `if (Username != null)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Sql Server null and C# null are two different concepts. Null in SQL Server means the i-do-not-know rather than not existing. So make that part of the query called in TSQL rather than in your application per se

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a simple if statement before your expressions.

```
if(Connection.Username!=null){
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select UserName from CustomerTrans  where UserName='"+Connection.Username+"'" , con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
            }
}
```

Comment: What if in case i have more than one where condition.Example Username,Children.....???

Comment: Then add them to the if statement with && (and) operation. Like if((Connection.Username!=null) && (Connection.Children!=null)) etc.